# How to check if string exists in array ('stdout_lines') returned by an Ansible task?

Tags: python, ansible

Im running an Ansible task and want to see if a substring exists in list that is returned by the task that is run, specifically `stdout_lines`.

The task uses the `win_shell` module and executes the following command: `netstat -aon | sls 8080"`.

In the case that process is running, the result will look like this:

```yaml
stdout_lines: [
    "",
    "",
    " TCP     127.0.0.1:8080     0.0.0.0:0      LISTENING 9196",
    ""
]
```

In Python I would do something like this to check if a substring existed in an element in a list.

```python
matching = [s for s in some_list if "8080" in s]
```

Is there a way to achieve that in Ansible?

Answer (score 4):

Two options I see.

First, you could do something like this:

```
- name: Capture output for analysis
  shell: "netstat -aon | sls 8080"
  register: netstat_output

- name: Check if the substring is in the output
  command: <do something else>
  when: "'some word' in {{netstat_output.stdout}}"
```

Another option is to breakout to a Python script and leverage that if the above still doesn't quite give you what you want.

```
- name: Run verification in Python
  script: some-script.py
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey. I tried something similar: failed_when: ' "8080" not in {{ output.stdout_lines}} ' but got an error that invalid conditional was detected. It looks like there is an 'in' but no, 'not in'. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html I'd rather not go with the script solution.

Comment: Negatives should work in Ansible too—`not defined`, `not in`, etc. ... it might be `is not in`?

Answer (score 0):

> *I tried something similar: `failed_when: ' "8080" not in {{ output.stdout_lines }} '` but got an error that invalid conditional was detected.*

Whereby [the already given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53104260/6771046) will result into an error message

```
The error was: template error while templating string
```

since [When should I use `{{ }}`? Also, how to interpolate variables or dynamic variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names), even without `{{ }}` a test like

```yaml
    when: "'8080' in result.stdout_lines"
```

would never become `true`.

According [Testing strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings), a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    result:
      stdout_lines:
        - ""
        - ""
        - " TCP     127.0.0.1:8080     0.0.0.0:0      LISTENING 9196"
        - ""

  tasks:

  - name: Check if a substring existed in an element in a list
    debug:
      msg: "No, does not contain 1234."
    when: result.stdout_lines is not search('1234')

  - name: Check if a substring existed in an element in a list
    debug:
      msg: "Yes, does contain 8080."
    when: result.stdout_lines is search('8080')
```

will result into the required output of

```yaml
TASK [Check if a substring existed in an element in a list] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: No, does not contain 1234.

TASK [Check if a substring existed in an element in a list] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Yes, does contain 8080.
```